# lWhy can't mysql open unix socket lock file?

Tags: mysql, macos

How can I solve the error *Could not open unix socket lock file /tmp/mysql.sock.lock.*?

I am using macOS.
I've reset mysql root password and left a memo. However, when I try to run mysql again a few days later, the access is denied. No solution suggested worked. So I reinstalled mysql. However, the access is still denied.
And when I try to run the server, it says that *ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file*.

This is my.cnf file:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
# pid
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

In the '***.err' file, it says that

```
2019-08-11T09:36:12.875813Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010274] [Server] Could not open unix socket lock file /tmp/mysql.sock.lock.
2019-08-11T09:36:12.875821Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010268] [Server] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
```

Comment: Does the file */tmp/mysql.sock.lock* exist before starting mysql? If yes you could look if some other process is locking the file.

Comment: How can I find that?

Comment: *lsof* could do this.

Comment: I entered *lsof /tmp/mysql.sock.lock*. Is this correct? (Nothing appeared)